# Unit Testing a Business Logic Interface

Tags: c#, nunit, moq

Am I going about this the right way? And if so, am I understanding it correctly? I am a little confused.

My project is setup in three different layers. The UI Layer, the Business Layer, and the Data Access Layer. The Business Layer and Data Access Layer are both built off of interfaces.

I am attempting to write Unit Tests using NUnit and Moq.

Here is my example. I want to test GetSum(int x, int y), which is a simple function that just returns x + y. This function exists in CalculatorLogic and implements ICalculatorLogic.

```
public class CalculatorLogic : ICalculatorLogic
{
    public int GetSum(int x, int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

Now, here is how I am attempting to write a UnitTest.

```
[TestFixture]
public class CalculatorLogicTests
{
    Mock<ICalculatorLogic> calculatorLogicMock;
    ICalculatorLogic calculatorLogic;

    public CalculatorLogicTests()
    {
        calculatorLogicMock = new Mock<ICalculatorLogic>();

        // now i need to do this setup, right?
        calculatorLogicMock.Setup(x => x.GetSum(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(6);

        calculatorLogic = calculatorLogicMock.Object;
    }

    [Test]
    public void GetSum_Test()
    {
        int expectedResult = 3 + 3;

        var sum = calculatorLogic.GetSum(3, 3);
        Assert.AreEqual(sum, expectedResult);
    }
}
```

Now, the above passes. It runs, and it gets what I am expecting. However, it feels wrong. It's just returning whatever I set it to return in the Setup() call. If I had put a 3 in the Returns() instead of the 6, it would fail.

I must be understanding something wrong. Otherwise, am I really testing my function if I'm telling it what to return?

Comment: Anything you mock is not tested so that is a pointless test as you have surmised. Hopefully your business logic classes have the data access dependencies injected into them, those are the things you want to mock so you can still actually exercise your business logic.

Comment: [I have a blog post](https://contrivedexample.com/2017/11/05/organizing-service-mocks-in-unit-tests/) you might find helpful.

Comment: So should I not be implementing my business logic from interfaces? I am also using dependency injection in my controllers and loading the business logic into them that way. I am going to read your article now. Thanks.

Comment: Interfacing your BL is up to you. I tend not to, but use virtual methods if I do need to mock something. There are few cases where I don't want to always run the business logic.

Comment: You should use mocking to eliminate dependencies not the logic

Answer (score 0):

Okay so you've got an interface `ICalculatorLogic` and an implementation of said interface `CalculatorLogic` that you wish to write tests for.

You're using a mocking framework `Moq` to mock dependencies that your `CalculatorLogic` does not have. You should write something like this:

```
[TestFixture]
public class CalculatorLogicTests
{
    // Our unit under test.
    ICalculatorLogic calculatorLogic;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        // This method is called for every [Test] in this class.
        // So let's recreate our CalculatorLogic here so that each
        // test has a fresh instance.
        calculatorLogic = new CalculatorLogic();
    }

    [Test]
    public void GetSum_WithTwoIntegers_ReturnsTheirSum()
    {
        // Arrange
        int expectedResult = 3 + 3;

        // Act
        var sum = calculatorLogic.GetSum(3, 3);

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(sum, expectedResult);
    }
}
```

Now let's say you want your `GetSum` to log the parameters that it is called with. You might create a logger interface like so:

```
public interface ILogger {
    void Log(int x, int y);
}
```

You then put it as a dependency by requiring it in the constructor of your `CalculatorLogic` class:

```
public class CalculatorLogic : ICalculatorLogic
{
    private readonly ILogger logger;

    // Now we have a dependency on ILogger!
    public CalculatorLogic(ILogger l) {
        logger = l;
    }

    public int GetSum(int x, int y)
    {
        // Let's log those numbers!
        logger.Log(x, y);
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

Then you can write your tests like so (using `Moq`):

```
[TestFixture]
public class CalculatorLogicTests
{
    // This guy we want to test.
    ICalculatorLogic calculatorLogic;

    // Our mock!
    Mock<ILogger> loggerMock;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        // Create the logger mock!
        loggerMock = new Mock<ILogger>();

        // Inject the logger into our CalculatorLogic!
        calculatorLogic = new CalculatorLogic(loggerMock.Object);
    }

    [Test]
    public void GetSum_WithTwoIntegers_ShouldCallLogger()
    {
        // Arrange
        int expectedResult = 3 + 3;

        // Act
        var sum = calculatorLogic.GetSum(3, 3);

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(sum, expectedResult);

        // Verify that the logger's Log method was called once with x = 3 and y = 3.
        loggerMock.Verify(logger => logger.Log(It.Is<int>(x => x == 3), It.Is<int>(y => y == 3)), Times.Once());
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to point out that `Assert.AreEqual(sum, expectedResult);` is incorrect. The first parameter of that method signature is the *expected* value and the second is the *actual* value. This incorrect order would lead to an incorrect message if the assertion fails. This illogical order is why NUnit's constraint-based syntax has become popular, which 'reads' better in English: `Assert.That(sum, Is.EqualTo(expectedResult));`